# can't work node.js server with nginx, the page is always nginx welcome page

Tags: nginx, node.js

I start a node.js server on the aws cloud, the location of the server is /home/ubuntu/home/fablab. I can start my node.js server with nginx in port 80, everything is working fine.

Then I am following the [tutorial](http://www.miguelmota.com/blog/nodejs-and-ngnix-on-ubuntu/) to work node.js and nginx on the server, I reconfigure the node.js port to 61337, build a fablab.conf under the folder of /etc/nginx/sites-available, 
and then ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/fablab.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/fablab.conf.
This is my fablab.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name fablab;

    location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
        root /home/ubuntu/node/fablab/public;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    client_max_body_size 16M;

    root /home/ubuntu/node/fablab;
    index /home/ubuntu/node/fablab/public/forum.html;   

    location / {
        access_log off;     
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:61337;

        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host  $http_host;
        #proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;

        # websockets support
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```

I reload and restart the nginx, and when I go to the server IP address and port 80, the page is still nginx's welcome page.

Why it doesn't work so far, everything I missed out? I think the key for the fablab.conf, is the `proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:61337`, is it already?

I have two confusions

1. do I have to use the default.conf in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, some other names are ok?
2. in the conf file, server_name is supposed to be host name, what if I only have IP address, not host name right now, how to do in this host name. as it is on AWS, do i need to fill in this as the my aws serer's domain name like ec2-24-210-148-112.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
3. in the [tutorial](http://www.miguelmota.com/blog/nodejs-and-ngnix-on-ubuntu/), server_name in the conf file is saying like this :

   ## Make sure to set the A Record on your domain's DNS settings to your server's IP address.

   ## You can test if was set properly by using the `dig` command: dig yourdomain.com

what does it mean ? how would I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration seems to be using Virtual Hosting; in other words, nginx decides "which" `server{..}` block matches a request based on the host the request specifies.  If the hostname specified doesn't correspond to any server_name, you'll end up with the default catch all site.

Your host name isn't a valid DNS name, but have no fear - put <kbd>fablab</kbd> in `/etc/hosts` (winderz puts it in Windows\System 32\drivers\etc ) something like this (specify your webserver's IP ) :

```
192.168.100.17 fablab
```

which should allow your host to resolve fablab to that Ip, and then NGINX should be able to route your request to the proper server.

Hope it Helps!